# Powershell get aduser query by the emailaddress

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to get the AD user list query by email address. I managed to get the report however, I can't export it to a CSV file. I don't know which part gets wrong.

really much appreciate it if someone can guide me.

Thanks.

here is the script I made.

```
$ADUsers = Import-csv "C:\temp\DevicesWithInventory_6db9330a-4377-4057-bc86-837f55fee3f6.csv"
$email= $user.Primaryuseremailaddress

foreach ($user in $ADUsers) {

   get-aduser -Filter {emailaddress -eq $email} -Properties * | select name,mail, whencreated, company,cn,country 
   } | Export-Csv -path c:\temp\intune_add_country.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$email= $user.Primaryuseremailaddress` be inside the loop?

Comment: You can't pipe `Export-Csv` directly from a `foreach` loop, either change your loop for a `ForEach-Object` or `.foreach({..})` or capture the result of the loop to a variable and then pipe that variable to `Export-Csv`

Comment: Thanks @SantiagoSquarzon
I follow your advice, it works "capture the result of the loop to a variable and then pipe that variable to Export-Csv"

Answer (score 1):

this is the amended script

```
$ADUsers = Import-csv "C:\temp\DevicesWithInventory_6db9330a-4377-4057-bc86-837f55fee3f6.csv"

$result = ForEach ($user in $ADUsers) {
    $email= $user.PrimaryuserUPN

   get-aduser -Filter {emailaddress -eq $email} -Properties * | select name,mail, whencreated, company,cn,country  
   }    
   
    $result| Export-Csv -path c:\temp\intune_add_country.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

despite the error, I get the report result that I want.
[image: error]

Comment: The errors are likely caused by empty values on that column (`PrimaryuserUPN`) of your Csv. You can optimize your code by changing `-Properties *` for only the list of attributes you want to query (`mail, whencreated, company, cn, country` - `name` is a default one, you don't need to add it)

Comment: Thanks @SantiagoSquarzon  .

really helpful